# Optimizing performance in an ExtJS app

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I've got an application that is heavy on field usage. I noticed that adding new fields can be fairly expensive, even when using suspend/resumelayouts. Observing the timeline in Chrome, I can see quite a lot of recalculation of styles and forced layouts (seems like one per fields) for the panel div.
The code below is a simple representation of what I'm doing.

```
util = {
    createTextField: function(myItemId) {
    return Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
        fieldLabel: 'Field' + myItemId + ':',
        name: 'field',
        itemId: myItemId,
        autofocus: true,
        enableKeyEvents: true,
        labelAlign: 'left',
        labelWidth: 50,
        labelStyle: 'font-size: 16px;',
        width: 500
    });
}
}


Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            for(i=0; i<100; i++)
            {
                Ext.suspendLayouts();
                formPanel.add(util.createTextField(i));
                Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
            }
        }
    });

    var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame: true,
        title: 'Form Fields',
        width: 340,
        height: 600,
        bodyPadding: 5,
        autoScroll: true,

        fieldDefaults: {
            labelAlign: 'left',
            labelWidth: 90
        }});


    formPanel.render('form-ct'); 

});
```

The page itself is fairly straightforward:

```
<body>
    <div id="form-ct"></div>
</body>
```

Right now pressing the button takes roughly ~2 seconds in Chrome and almost 4 in IE11. My question is whether this can be somehow optimized. Note that the fields must be rendered dynamically. I'm using ExtJS 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

Start with moving suspendLayout/resumeLayout pair *outside* of the loop:

```
        Ext.suspendLayouts();
        for(i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            formPanel.add(util.createTextField(i));
        }
        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
```

Calling these inside the loop basically defeats the whole purpose of suspending layouts because you are forcing a relayout no less than 100 times in a row.

Comment: Whoops, my bad! Thanks for that. I actually do have it outside the loop in my original code, I just messed up this sample. Any other tips?

Comment: Lots of them. Try Googling for "Ext JS performance", the first hit is this excellent article: https://www.sencha.com/blog/ext-js-4-1-performance/

Answer (score 1):

The [`add`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-method-add) method is firing two events, [`add`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-event-add) and [`beforeadd`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-event-beforeadd). You can instead using an array with components to add all at ones. Besides that you can use [defaults](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-defaults) and [defaultType](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.form.Panel-cfg-defaultType), but that will not do much I guess.

```
util = {
    createTextField: function(myItemId) {
        return Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Text', {
            fieldLabel: 'Field' + myItemId + ':',
            name: 'field' + myItemId // names are unique, we will use this to query components
        });
    }
}

Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'Click me',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        handler: function() {
            // array to hold all components
            var components = new Array();

            // optimize the for loop and introduce y
            for(var i = 0, y = 100; i < y; i++)
                components.push(util.createTextField(i));

            // add all components at ones to prevent multiple events fired
            Ext.suspendLayouts();
            formPanel.add(components);
            Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
        }
    });

    var formPanel = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        frame: true,
        title: 'Form Fields',
        width: 340,
        height: 600,
        bodyPadding: 5,
        autoScroll: true,

        // use defaultType and defaults to clean the code
        defaultTypes: 'textfield',
        defaults: {
            autofocus: true,
            enableKeyEvents: true, // this is heavy, consider if it is required
            labelAlign: 'left',
            labelWidth: 50,
            labelStyle: 'font-size: 16px;',
            width: 500
        }
    });

    formPanel.render('form-ct'); 
});
```

Comment: Hmm, are you sure about the array not firing events? I'm still seeing a bunch of "Install Timer" and "Remove Timer" in the timeline, all related to firing "onItemAdd".